# UIScrollView tap gesture not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, view-hierarchy

I have an application where I am creating and adding `PrimaryViewController` to a `UIScrollView`, when the user taps on a button on `PrimaryViewController`'s view, I create and add a `SecondViewController` to the `UIScrollView`.  The `SecondViewController` creates and adds a new `UIScrollView` to it's view.

My problem is this: I need to get a tap event on the `SecondViewController`'s UIScrollView.  But when I tap on the `SecondViewController`'s `UIScrollView` it throws an error (unrecognized selector).  I believe it has to do with the view hierarchy and the fact that I am creating a new `SecondViewController` each time the button on `PrimaryViewController`'s view is tapped (which I need to do).  Does anyone know how to solve this view-hierarchy issue?  If you need more of an explanation let me know.

Comment: "Throws an error" is not much explanatory

Comment: why you are adding view on scrollview? why not adding it PrimaryViewController's view?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. I am adding the primary view controllers view to the UIScroll view.  Also, the error that is being thrown doesn't say anything other than it is a unrecognized selector.

Comment: It should say something like `-[Class selector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. The first half there is the important part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me solve my issue.  I was creating a new SecondViewController each time the PrimaryViewController's button was tapped. I changed it so I just update the data in the SecondViewController instead of creating an entirely new view controller.  I still don't quite understand the problem, but will update this post if I figure out why.